# Imagemagick batch convert to webp, without making an animation

Tags: imagemagick, webp

I want to convert PNGs to webp, for that I use :

```
convert *.png -quality 90% -set filename:basename "%[basename]" "optim/%[filename:basename]".webp
```

Instead of writing one webp per png, I get one webp file with all the images as an animation.

I'm pretty sure I used a similar command in the past with success, I'm now using ImageMagick 7.0.8-68 on Macos.

What should I add to get individual WEBPs instead of an animation?

Edit: here's a full test case, ImageMagick installed through Homebrew, version 7.0.9-5 Q16 x86_64 2019-11-18

Create multiple PNGs :

```
for i in {1..9}; do convert -background black -fill grey -font impact -size 320x240 -pointsize 96 -gravity center label:$i out-$i.png; done
```

then attempt to convert to individual WEBPs:

```
convert *.png -quality 90% -set filename:basename "%[basename]" "optim/%[filename:basename]".webp
```

Result here is one WEBP file containing all images as an animation.

Comment: Your command fails for me because the folder `optim` did not exist.  When the folder `optim` does exist it converts and does not create an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a confirmed bug in ImageMagick : https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37104&p=170508